# Two dicts One Val

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using python 3.5, please explain result of code:

```
dict1={}
dict1['a']= 'one %s two'
dict2=dict1
print(dict1)
dict2['a']=dict1['a'] % 'less than' # changing one of dict2 values, 
print(dict1)                        # but also changes dict 1 value 
                                    # with same key
```

why after this code dict1['a'] value becomes 'one less than two'?

Comment: You do not have two dicts. You have one dict.

Comment: Read this : https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, everything is an object. When you write `dict1 = {}` what you're doing is assigning an *instance* of the dictionary object which is empty, `dict()` to the object named `dict1`.  But when you write this line `dict2=dict1`, you're telling python to assign the object `dict2` to reference the *exact* same object as `dict1`.  Meaning whatever changes happen to one will happen to the other.

What you would want to do is write `dict2 = dict(dict1)`, which tells python `dict2` is a new instance of the dictionary object which is the same values of `dict1`.  Now when you change the value in one it won't affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

bruno desthuilliers comment is best answer

**end edit**

object in almost all languages are same , when u set `dict2 = dict1` they will be same at memory

if u want to create coppy u must create a **shalowcopy** or **deepcopy** in python

```
dict2 = dict(dict1) # create a copy of dict1
```

`x = {}`

```
y=x # this make y pointer to x and two are one
```

Comment: why so different reaction when assigning dicts and simple variables or lists?

Comment: lists and dicts behave the same way, only unstructured types like int, str,bool etc do not have the referential behavior

Comment: Actually in either case when you do y=x you're still assigning the exact same object to both y and x.  The only reason it doesn't behave the same is because literals are immutable so there's no way for you did change x without resigning. Logically speaking, to copy it you should be doing `y = str(x)`.

Comment: @keksnicoh list of unstructured types is also like unstructred type , so u cant say list are same

Comment: @NozarSafari see my edit.  Just because it works doesn't mean it's wrong.  If the literals are somehow mutable it'll not work at all.

Comment: Please people stop writing nonsense and get your facts straights. Assignment works the same way for __all__ types and __never__ copies anything, it is documented, explained in great details (notably here : https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and can be verified very simply using the `id(obj)` function and/or the identity test operator `is`.

Comment: @Idlehands thanks for good comment i dont now how highlight your comment . if possible edit my answer and put your comment in it

Comment: @NozarSafari I invite you to read the article linked in my comment above. Idlehands is right, you are wrong, and that's a fact, period.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i already say thank to idlehands and thank to u too, you are right